# Format() return string not a number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have that :

```
Date                 |  var1   |  var2 | var3 
2018-03-08 23:23:14  |   1.2   |   100 |  2.54
2018-03-09 20:00:14  |   1.0   |   100 |  2.554
2018-03-10 22:23:14  |   5.23  |   100 |  2.11
2018-03-12 18:21:14  |   4.22  |   100 |  0.2
```

I want that :

```
Date                 |  var1   |  var2 | var3 
2018-03-08 23:23:14  |   1.200 |   100 |  2.540
2018-03-09 20:00:14  |   1.000 |   100 |  2.554
2018-03-10 22:23:14  |   5.230 |   100 |  2.110
2018-03-12 18:21:14  |   4.220 |   100 |  0.200
```

I did this function :

```
data['var1'] = data['var1'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.3f'))
data['var3'] = data['var3'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.3f'))
```

function Format() returns a string not a number. 
thank you !

Comment: What about: `type(data['var1'])` ? What about `format` ? `Format` return a string data type - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting . If you want a ineteger output, use the `str` function to convert - `str(data['var1'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.3f')))`

Comment: Is this a bug or just a statement? Do you want to have a float but with higher precision?

Comment: How are you displaying the table? Note: version `0.23` already pads to a consistent length (`.2f` var1 and `.3f` var3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has an option `display.float_format` which is a function (default `None`) that takes a single float and returns the string necessary to display, e.g.:

```
In []:
pd.options.display.float_format

Out[]:
None:

In []:
print(df)

Out[]:
   Date                     var1       var2    var3 
0  2018-03-08 23:23:14         1.20      100   2.540
1  2018-03-09 20:00:14         1.00      100   2.554
2  2018-03-10 22:23:14         5.23      100   2.110
3  2018-03-12 18:21:14         4.22      100   0.200

In []:
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format  # or lambda f: format(f, '.3f')
print(df)

Out[]:
   Date                     var1       var2    var3 
0  2018-03-08 23:23:14        1.200      100   2.540
1  2018-03-09 20:00:14        1.000      100   2.554
2  2018-03-10 22:23:14        5.230      100   2.110
3  2018-03-12 18:21:14        4.220      100   0.200
```

Note: this doesn't change the underlying value but just forces a display.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1.2, 1.0, 5.23, 4.22]})
print(df["a"].map('{:.3f}'.format))
```

**Output:**

```
0    1.200
1    1.000
2    5.230
3    4.220
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

As you point out, your code will change the type of the columns to string, which will break compatibility with numerical operations. In fact, I don't think that you want to change the *values* inside the two columns, just the way values are printed. For doing so, you can take a look at the pandas styling notation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html.